# Wifi stopped working on 14.04

Tags: wireless

I followed your advices and here the info I gathered: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15406786/

The wifi was working fine until some days ago. Cable internet is ok though.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: If you follow the answer, it should eventually lead you to `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` and you may have to blacklist ssb and b43 modules although bcmwl-kernel-source sometimes works

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem recently. I used following steps to solve the issue :

1. open terminal (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or go to dash and type terminal)
2. `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo update-pciids`
5. `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`
6. `sudo reboot`